# Heroku Python FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am working on a Flask app that is hosted on Heroku. This app works with files that are locally hosted.

In my local machine, the app works perfectly, and opens files in a specific directory: `/project/files`.

However, when I deploy the app to production in Heroku, it gives me the following message for the local directory:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here is my code:

```
s = sftp.Connection(host=SFTP_HOSTNAME, username=SFTP_USERNAME, password=SFTP_PASSWORD, cnopts=cnopts)
    localFilePath = '/app/app/sftpfiles'
    remoteFilePath = '/files/client'
    
    files = s.listdir_attr(remoteFilePath)
    if files == []:
        return "empty"
    else:
        for f in files:
            if f.filename.endswith('.csv'):
                randomint = str(random.randint(1000,9999))
                datenow = str(datetime.now().date())
                lPath = localFilePath + '/' + f.filename
                newlPath = localFilePath + '/' + f.filename + '-' + datenow + '-' + randomint
                s.get(remoteFilePath + '/'  + f.filename, lPath)
                os.rename(lPath, newlPath)
                [...]
```

Logs:

```
2022-07-13T09:16:34.603426+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection succesfully established...
2022-07-13T09:16:34.603590+00:00 app[web.1]: Root Path:  /app/app
2022-07-13T09:16:34.603669+00:00 app[web.1]: CONNECTION IS:  <pysftp.Connection object at 0x7f93566e5960>
2022-07-13T09:16:34.706901+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection succesfully established...
2022-07-13T09:16:34.707053+00:00 app[web.1]: Root Path:  /app/app
2022-07-13T09:16:34.707092+00:00 app[web.1]: CONNECTION IS:  <pysftp.Connection object at 0x7f93578c6b30>
2022-07-13T09:16:35.926913+00:00 app[web.1]: BEFORE DOWNLOADING THE FILE app/sftpfiles/testagainok.csv-2022-07-13-6651
2022-07-13T09:16:35.943975+00:00 app[web.1]: BEFORE DOWNLOADING THE FILE app/sftpfiles/testagainok.csv-2022-07-13-9316
2022-07-13T09:16:36.082532+00:00 app[web.1]: AFTER DOWNLOADING THE FILE, HERE IS THE RESPONSE:
2022-07-13T09:16:36.094290+00:00 app[web.1]: Job "sync_work_days (trigger: interval[0:00:05], next run at: 2022-07-13 09:16:39 UTC)" raised an exception
2022-07-13T09:16:36.094292+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-07-13T09:16:36.094292+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 125, in run_job
2022-07-13T09:16:36.094295+00:00 app[web.1]: retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
2022-07-13T09:16:36.094296+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app/sftp.py", line 32, in sync_work_days
2022-07-13T09:16:36.094296+00:00 app[web.1]: s.get(remoteFilePath + '/'  + f.filename, lPath)
2022-07-13T09:16:36.094297+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 249, in get
2022-07-13T09:16:36.094297+00:00 app[web.1]: self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, callback=callback)
2022-07-13T09:16:36.094297+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 812, in get
2022-07-13T09:16:36.094298+00:00 app[web.1]: s = os.stat(localpath)
2022-07-13T09:16:36.094298+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'app/sftpfiles/testagainok.csv'
2022-07-13T09:16:39.610429+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection succesfully established...
2022-07-13T09:16:39.610592+00:00 app[web.1]: Root Path:  /app/app
2022-07-13T09:16:39.610658+00:00 app[web.1]: CONNECTION IS:  <pysftp.Connection object at 0x7f93568520b0>
2022-07-13T09:16:39.692308+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection succesfully established...
2022-07-13T09:16:39.692435+00:00 app[web.1]: Root Path:  /app/app
```

Here is the directory I'm trying to access on Heroku:
[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Trying to open a file on Heroku:

I added the following code:

```
print("TRYING OPENING A FILE")
f = open("/app/app/sftpfiles/testfile.csv")
print("results of the file are: ", f)
```

I created the file: `touch /app/app/sftpfiles/testfile.csv`

And here is file:

[image]

And here are the results:

```
2022-07-13T13:19:15.443344+00:00 app[web.1]: f = open("/app/app/sftpfiles/testfile.csv")
2022-07-13T13:19:15.443345+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/app/sftpfiles/testfile.csv'
```

Comment: Would simple `open(localFilePath + '/' + f.filename, "wb")` create the local file? I'm sure it would fail with the same error => You mostly likely do not have [tag:pysftp]/[tag:paramiko] question. And actually not even [tag:python]/programming question, as you seem to be writing to a non-existing path. In any case, we need [mcve].

Comment: I do not think it's a [tag:heroku] issue either. It seem to be a simple path issue. If it were the permission issue, you would be getting a permission error, not `FileNotFoundError`. So did you try `~/app/sftpfiles`? Or whatever *absolute path* does it resolve too (seems to be `/app/app/sftpfiles`)? + We are still waiting for [mcve]. + Though best would be if you login to `SFTP_USERNAME@SFTP_HOSTNAME` with any GUI SFTP client (like WinSCP) and check what is the actual public SFTP path.

Comment: I already showed the path in the screenshot I put on the edit. It shows exactly the path of the directory I'm not able to access.

Comment: The screenshot shows some kind of a shell. The shell is not SFTP.  The path might be same in SFTP, but it also might not. Stop finding excuses for not providing us the information we ask for. And based on your screenshot, I've suggested two paths to try. And you didn't seem to even try that!?!

Comment: Ok I think you are missing the whole question. Let me explain this once more. You have a flask app, deployed on Heroku, this app connects via SFTP to a server elsewhere to download a file. When the app tries to download the file LOCALLY (meaning on Heroku premises) it gives this error. This has nothing to do with SFTP. The problem that I have is local to Heroku, not in SFTP. And Yes, I DID TRY BOTH PATHS, and it did not work.

Comment: It seems to me that you are confused, so let me once again re explain it in layman's terms: You have a flask app, that tries to open a file on a local folder, it works on your local Windows machine, it does NOT work when it's deployed to Heroku. Plain and simple. Do you have an idea about working with files and folders on the ephemeral disk of Heroku? If yes, please enlighten me. If not, I hope someone else can get to this question.

Comment: results of the getcwd are:  /app

Comment: And I think you meant os.listdir("/")

Comment: results of the listdir '/' are:  ['sbin', 'bin', 'var', 'sys', 'app', 'dev', 'tmp', 'usr', 'etc', 'proc', 'lib64', 'lost+found', 'lib']

Comment: results of the listdir '.' are:  ['.profile.d', 'requirements.txt', '__pycache__', 'app', 'runtime.txt', 'Procfile', 'wsgi.py', '.heroku']

Comment: There imo still too much SFTP in your question, while none is needed. + What do `os.listdir("/app/app")` and `os.listdir("/app/app/sftpfiles")` return?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
localFilePath = '/app/sftpfiles'
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work, same error. Any path I put, cannot be read.